# Positive definiteness of a certain matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, positive-definite

Given a $n\times n$ P.D. matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D = \mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$, with $d_i > 0$, $i=1\ldots,n$, I want to prove that the product $AD$ is also positive definite.

Since $A$ is positive definite, all its leading principal minors will be positive.

Let with $|\cdot|_k$ denote the $k$-th leading principal minor and let with $[\cdot]_{R,C}$, where $R, C$ are $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, denote the $k\times k$ minor that corresponds to the rows with index in $R$ and the columns with index in $C$.

From the formula in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications), we get
$$
|AD|_k = [AD]_{I,I}  \sum_K [A]_{I,K} [D]_{K,I},
$$
where $I = \{1, \ldots, k\}$ and the sum extends over all subsets $K$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ with $k$ elements.

However, since $D$ is diagonal, every minor with $K \neq I$ will be zero. Thus,
$$
|AD|_k = [A]_{I,I} [D]_{I,I} = |A|_k |D|_k,
$$
which will be positive for all $k$, and as such $AD$ is positive definite.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: $AD$ is not symmetric matrix. What is your definition of positive definite?

Comment: According to wikipedia again, you can call a matrix p.d. if it satisfies $x^T A x >0$, even if it is not symmetric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-symmetric_matrices

Comment: Then the Sylvester criterion (leading principal minors) does not work. Moreover, it is not true. Example: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4\\0 & 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 20\\0 & 25\end{bmatrix}$.